# Getting list of messages from Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to call Twilio services into my node application.

According to docs I am calling list of messages service like bellow

```
var accountSid = 'ACe622fda3d3cd03b3b975d8d92f7c794b';
var authToken = "your_auth_token";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.list(function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
    });
});
```

As a result I am getting first 50 messages with complete details.

Now my issue is how to get previous messages(pagination), conversations between two numbers and using further filters like date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[List resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) return [pagination information](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information), including the next and previous pages' URLs. You can also set the page size.

So, for a first pass you can get more than 50 messages by setting the PageSize to the maximum 1000.

```
client.messages.list({ PageSize: 1000 }, function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body);
    });
});
```

If you need to go beyond that, then you can use the next page url to get the next page:

```
var url = require("url");

client.messages.list(function(err, data) {
  if (data.next_page_uri) {
    // deal with page 1
    var query = url.parse(data.next_page_uri, true).query;
    client.messages.list(query, function(err, data) {
      // and so on
    }
  }
});
```

[Adam Varga shared a solution he was using](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/11) on GitHub (it's for phone numbers, but lists all act the same on Twilio). Also, look out for the release of version 3 of the Node.js library, which will include pagination helpers.